# Router.push makes page flash and changes url to localhost:3000/?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

After pushing a route in NextJS the path seems to be valid for a split of a second `http://localhost:3000/search?query=abc` and then changes to `http://localhost:3000/?`. Not sure why this is happening.

I have tried it with both `import Router from 'next/router'` and `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'`. Same problem for both import types.

Here's my component and I use the `route.push` once user submits a search form.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Router from 'next/router';

const SearchInput = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSearching) {
      Router.push({
        pathname: "/search",
        query: { query: searchValue },
      });
      setIsSearching(false);
    }
  }, [isSearching, searchValue]);

  const handleSearch = () => {
    if (searchValue) {
      setIsSearching(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>
      <input
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={(event) => setSearchValue(event.target.value)}
        placeholder="Search"
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of form submissions to refresh the browser and render a new HTML page.

You need to call `e.preventDefault()` inside **handleSearch**.

```
 const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (searchValue) {
      setIsSearching(true);
    }
  };
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: welcome, I struggled with this a long time ago too :')